# Save Json data to ArrayList

Tags: android, android-jsinterface

I want to read each element and store each json element in an arraylist efficiently from the  json format data below

```
   getData =  {"block_id":"2","body":"<p>json data" }


        String id = getData.getString("block_id");
        String name = getData.getString("body");
```

Comment: Your data is very less to predict anything.

Comment: There is a missing quote in the JSON which makes it invlaid. and are you looking for a solution specific to this JSON data.?

Comment: i want to retrieve block_id and body and store it in an arraylist

Comment: first get json data in separate and then store it into arraylist..

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/ just check out this link and try to understand how JSON parsing works. you could get answers for these type of questions in google without downvotes and criticism.

Answer (score 0):

You may use following code which retreiving json data

HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
             HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);

```
         String url = your url;

         Log.v(TAG, "URL In onPreExecute"+url);
         HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

try 
        {
            response = client.execute(request);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             ent=entity.toString();
              if(entity!=null)
              {
                  InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream));
                  builder = new StringBuilder();
                  String line = null;
                  while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
                  {
                      builder.append(line);
                  }
                  instream.close();
                  Log.v("CMH", "Result of http " + builder.toString());
                }
                else
                {
                     Log.v("Data", "Failed to download file");
                }


              JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
                //      String csSuccess = jsonObject.getString("vidlist");
                        jsonarray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("vidlist");
                        NumOfObjects  = jsonarray.length();
                        Log.v(TAG, "NumOfObjects "+NumOfObjects);

                for(int Video = 0; Video < NumOfObjects; Video++)
                    {
                        SetterGetter setget = new SetterGetter();

                        video_obj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(Video);


                    String id = video_obj.getString("video_id"));


                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ArrayList declaration,

```
private ArrayList<Integer> idList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        private ArrayList<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Once you successfully parsed the data,

```
 String id = getData.getString("block_id");
  String name = getData.getString("body");

  //Here added into arraylist...

  idList.add(id);
  nameList.add(name);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonstring);

String id = json.getString("block_id");
String name = json.getString("body");

ArrayList<String> arrIds = new ArrayList<String>();
arrIds.add(id);
```